# groovy MissingMethodException - parsing through ConfigSlurper

Tags: groovy

I am trying to parse through some properties file using configslurper.

```
ENT.adminserver.nodenumber=1
ENT.managedserver.1.host=vserver04
ENT.managedserver.2.host=vserver05
ENT.managedserver.3.host=vserver08
ENT.managedserver.4.host=vserver07
```

Said properties file. I am trying to read the host names from the properties.

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
File propertiesFile = new File('DomainBuild.properties')
propertiesFile.withInputStream {properties.load(it)}
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(properties)

    def domainname="ENT" //will be passed through paremeters
    def domain = config.get(domainname)
    def managedServerFlow= {
      println domain.managedserver
      println domain.managedserver.keySet()
      domain.managedserver.each { 
        println it.getClass()
        println it.get("1") 
      }

      for (server in domain.managedserver) {
        println server.getClass()
        println server
      }
    }
}
```

the it.get("1") is causing the following error.

```
No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry.get() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [1]
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), grep(), grep(java.lang.Object), wait(), getKey(), any()
```

I looked through the java and groovy doc and spent few hours without resolution. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
println it.get("1")
```

Try

```
println it.'1'
```

Or

```
println it.getAt("1") // as the exception shows you
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about what types you are working with. `config` is a `ConfigObject`, which you can treat like a map. Its sub-objects `domain` and `domain.managedserver` are also ConfigObjects. When you call `each` on `domain.managedserver` and pass it a closure that takes no parameters, it gives you a set of Entries. Therefore you can't call `it.get("1")` because an `Entry` doesn't have a property called "1". It has `key` and `value`. So you can either `println "$it.key: $it.value"` or

```
  domain.managedserver.each { key, value ->
    println value.getClass()
    println "$key: $value"
  }
```

or if you want to get the value for key "1" directly:

```
  println domain.managedserver.'1'
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail. Initially I tried the standard java for loop, `foreach(server in domain.managedservers)` and got stuck in the .get .put mindset. the key and value makes sense.